# Finding which condition Failed in MYSQL Query (Deviation Summary)

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I need to show a Deviation Summary if any of the mysql query condition faied. I need to show which data input was wrong due to which I got NONE Results.

More of a Logical Problem so tried to google around for the same.

Table Fields : 
id , day , date , time , program , title

Query

```
SELECT Count(id) FROM `table` 
WHERE day='Monday' and date = '2018-10-15' and time = '19:45:34' and title = 'NEW-BOTTLE'
```

Above query will return count if the all condition are satisfied. I need to show a Deviation Summary in case any of the Condition values got Unsatisfied.

For Example if NEW-BOTTLE is input as NEW-BOTTLE1 than I need to show that  title Name is incorrrect.

In the same way I need to show which value was wrong due to which count 0 occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` conditions for selecting values as below:

```
SELECT IF(day = 'Monday', 'TRUE','FALSE') as dayResult, IF(date = '2018-10-15', 'TRUE','FALSE') as dateResult,
IF(time = '19:45:34', 'TRUE','FALSE') as timeResult, IF(title = 'NEW-BOTTLE', 'TRUE','FALSE') as titleResult   FROM `table`
```

It will return the either `1` or `0` according to condition satisfaction. hope it helps you in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the switch statement to print the detailed summary. Here is the pseudo-code.

```
switch (true) {

case 0:
    SELECT Count(id) FROM `table`
    WHERE day = 'Monday' and date = '2018-10-15' and time = '19:45:34' and title = 'NEW-BOTTLE'
    // Get the count from query    

    if ($count != '0') {
        // Criteria met successfully, not need to check other cases;
        break;
    }

case 1:
    SELECT Count(id) FROM `table`
    WHERE day = 'Monday' and date = '2018-10-15' and time = '19:45:34'

    //get the count
    if ($count != '0')
        echo "Title is incorrect";

case 2:
    SELECT Count(id) FROM `table`
    WHERE day = 'Monday' and date = '2018-10-15' and title = 'NEW-BOTTLE'
    //get the count
    if ($count != '0')
        echo "Time didn't match";

case 3:
    SELECT Count(id) FROM `table`
    WHERE day = 'Monday' and time = '19:45:34' and title = 'NEW-BOTTLE'
    if ($count != '0')
        echo "Date didn't match";

case 4:
    SELECT Count(id) FROM `table`
    WHERE date = '2018-10-15' and time = '19:45:34' and title = 'NEW-BOTTLE'
    if ($count != '0')
        echo "Day didn't match";
}
```